# How to send customised information through an automated email in netsuite

Tags: email, customization, netsuite

Using Netsuite, I want to use Historical ordering data per customer to automate emails which tell customers about products or promotions

i.e. if the customer has ordered product X in the last 3 months, send them an email that its out of stock, or if they ordered product Y in the last 3 months, also tell them product Y is discounted

Does anyone know the best way to customise an email using data within Netsuite data so they are personalised per customer?

The other option is to send an order confirmation when they place an order with the customised information as part of this confirmation

The logic is simple, I would just like the best advice on implementation

Comment: Does your email depends on the item selected ? For some item say X you want to send a different message and for item Y different, is that right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a schedule script that runs on predefined schedule and then pull the customers based on your saved search logic and send mail individually to every customer using nlapiSendEmail()